# jQuery - Outlining incorrect or invalid fields in red.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a signup form and I would like to make incorrect fields have a red outline that signifies that there is an error. I have tried using jQuery Validator, but for some reason it didn't work.

Would there be any chance that anyone could provide an example on how to do this in jQuery using the following HTML markup?

```
<div class="content">
    <form class="formlogin" action="" method="POST">
        <p class="Title">Signup</p>
        <input id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text">
        <input id="Firstname" placeholder="First name" name="firstname" type="text">
        <input id="lastname" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" type="text">
        <input id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="text">
        <input id="password" placeholder="password" name="password" type="password">
        <input id="register" name="SignUp" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the google say?

Comment: As @Pavlo suggests, Google it. I'm sure the jQuery validator requires YOU to add a class to the required fields, something like `<input class="required" name="username" .. ` But just read up on where you downloaded your validator.

Comment: I dont find a lot of results on google , just some jquery plugins but nothing important

Comment: Why jquery plugin validator is not work for you?

Comment: i doesnt highlight the wrong fields in red

Comment: How about showing the javascript code where you assign the validator to the form and define the validation requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('form.formlogin').submit(function(f_submit) {
    var selector = $(this);        // I tent to store the element just in case I need to use it later.

    var input_username = selector.children("input#username"); // The username element.
    var input_email = selector.children("input#email"); // The email element.
    var val_username = input_username.val();    // Get the content of the username field.
    var val_email = input_email.val();
    var regex_username = /^[A-Za-z\d_-]+$/;    // In this example,
    // the characters after the "\d" in the regex are accepted. (the "_", and "-");
    var regex_email = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;

    if( val_username.match(regex_username) == null ) {
        input_username.css("border-color","#F00");
    } else {
        input_username.css("border-color","#000000");
    }

    if( val_email.match(regex_email) == null ) {
        input_email.css("border-color","#F00");
    } else {
        input_email.css("border-color","#000000");
    }

    // Prevent page refresh.
    // You can replace this with an AJAX system.
    return false;
});
```

Since it only took a few minutes to throw together, and it may not be the /best/ example, here's the link to it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F52mY/1/

Using jQuery 2.1.0, but I believe that 1.6.x and below work.

Comment: (f_submit) why the f there ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object form.formsignup has no method 'submit'  thats what it  sais un the console

Comment: Try including [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) in your HTML using the following: `<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>`

And according to JSFiddle, the example code works perfectly fine.